# Do I need a splash screen for an app to be submitted to app store

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is a splash screen required to submit your app into the app store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple discourages the use of splash screens. But you might need a default image. Which is a screenshot of your user interface without elements that are dynamic.

If you use a default image your users will think your app starts faster

Take my app as example for a recommended default image.

Real screenshot:

[image]

Default.png:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted several apps without any Default image or splash screen within the past year, and they have all been approved by Apple.  I've also not seen anything in the SDK agreement rules absolutely requiring such images.  But a Default image might be recommended in the HIG.

But also note, prior app approvals do not set any precedent.  Apple can change what they approve at will.

Answer (score 2):

There is detail in the HIG that suggests providing a Default image that is an "empty" version of your main view. The Facebook app does this, for example, and there are many others. Another common practice is to use a splash screen image that has nothing to do with your UI but is perhaps your logo or graphics from the app. Apple discourages this, but doesn't reject your app if you go this route. I have several apps published that have splash style Default images.

Overall, I think it's a good idea to provide something in a Default image (Default.png AND Default@2x.png) because it gives the user a visual indicator that *something* is happening.

My first app did not have a Default image, and while the app is loading, the screen is black. Not a great user experience and the user is left wondering: What is happening? For apps that take a long time to load, a Default image bridges the gap while the user waits for the app to load and start.

Answer (score 1):

No, not as far as I know. But it takes about 3 minutes to create one.

1. Create a screenshot of first screen the user sees
2. Open this screenshot in Preview
3. Do some copy & pasting to remove all the text and only leave blank buttons
4. Add image to Xcode and edit the Info.plist
5. Done!